# Windows Phone 8.1 Loading Images from Remote URLs Placeholder

Tags: c#, image, asynchronous, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1

I'm messing around with some windows phone development as I'm new to it coming from an Android background.

I am using "theCatAPI" to load a random picture of a cat and show it, then when the picture is clicked, or the button at the bottom of the screen, the image refreshes to a new one.

I have the following so far:

XAML:

```
<Page
    x:Class="CatFactsPics.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:CatFactsPics"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">

        <Grid.ChildrenTransitions>
            <TransitionCollection>
                <EntranceThemeTransition/>
            </TransitionCollection>
        </Grid.ChildrenTransitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!-- TitlePanel -->
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="24,17,0,28">
            <TextBlock Text="My Application" Style="{ThemeResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" Typography.Capitals="SmallCaps"/>
            <TextBlock Text="page title" Margin="0,12,0,0" Style="{ThemeResource HeaderTextBlockStyle}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <!--TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid-->
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot">
            <Image HorizontalAlignment="Center" Stretch="UniformToFill" VerticalAlignment="Center" x:Name="KittyPic" Tapped="KittyPic_Tapped"/>
            <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="newPic" Click="newPic_Click" >New Kitty</Button>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

and in the page.cs:

```
...
        protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            this.navigationHelper.OnNavigatedTo(e);

            Uri myUri = new Uri("http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            KittyPic.Source = new BitmapImage(myUri);
        }
...
        private void newPic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Uri myUri = new Uri("http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
            BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
            bmi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
            bmi.UriSource = myUri;
            KittyPic.Source = bmi;
        }
```

I have a couple of questions:

1) is this the correct way of doing things?  In Android I'd try and do things asynchronously to avoid stalling the UI thread.  That being said, I don't appear to be having any issues with things the way they are now. I'm not familiar with the Windows way of doing things, and haven't found any resources giving any explanation or advice on doing so.

2) There is a delay in displaying the new picture causing a short (couple of second) period where the image view turns black, before the new image reappears.  Is there a way of setting it up so either the old picture remains until the new one is physically ready to be displayed, or alternatively display a placeholder "loading" image until the new one can replace it.

Any other advice or tips on how to do things would be great, thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) With your current code you do not block the UI thread as yes you are setting the `URI` on the UI thread, but the actually loading of the image is done on another thread automatically. (For doing manually downloading of images, strings etc, you will probably use [async/await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) to avoid locking the UI thread).

2) The image goes black because you change the `ImageSource` before the new image has loaded. There are as you mention several ways to deal with this. Common for most of them though is that you will want to use the `ImageOpened` and `ImageFailed` events on the Image control, which triggers whenever the image is done loading (or an error occurred, for example no internet connection). Here is an example of displaying a loading bar while it is loading, which just hides/shows the loading progress:

In the `page.xaml` file:

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot">
    <Image x:Name="KittyPic" Tapped="KittyPic_Tapped" ImageOpened="KittyPic_ImageOpened" ImageFailed="KittyPic_ImageFailed" />
    <StackPanel x:Name="LoadingPanel" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <ProgressBar IsIndeterminate="True" IsEnabled="True" />
        <TextBlock Text="Loading image..." HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

And in the page.xaml.cs file

```
private void KittyPic_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    Uri myUri = new Uri("http://thecatapi.com/api/images/get?format=src&type=jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
    BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
    bmi.CreateOptions = BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache;
    bmi.UriSource = myUri;
    KittyPic.Source = bmi;
}

private void KittyPic_ImageOpened(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}

private async void KittyPic_ImageFailed(object sender, ExceptionRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadingPanel.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    await new MessageDialog("Failed to load the image").ShowAsync();
}
```

Instead of the `TextBlock` and `ProgressBar` you could of course show whatever you want, or for example swapping between two images to keep showing the old one.

For other advice I think when you got used to the basics is to take a look at [data bindings](http://jesseliberty.com/2012/08/10/windows-8-primerdata-binding-part-1/) which is very helpful and powerful. Also take a look at this article about [MVVM pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/gg521153%28v=vs.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for a great answer.  Much more detailed that I was even hoping for.  Microsoft have some great documentation and tips available, I'm just having a really tough time finding it.  Think they layout of it could do with some improvement

Comment: I've just spent a good few hours trying to follow that MVVM pattern tutorial and a majority of it is no good for WP8.1 as the namespaces have changed, for example local application settings work completely differently and simply changing namespace to Windows.Storage.Current.LocalSettings isn't sufficient.  I get the gist of it though

Answer (score 2):

1)  is this the correct way of doing things?

No. It's not. You should definitely adopt the MVVM pattern and detach your business logic from your view - meaning you shouldn't create bitmap images or request/assign such remote image URL's in your view's code-behind. You should be doing such stuff in your ViewModel and bind them to your View.

So in your case there will be an Uri (or a string where you will assign the remote URL) property in your ViewModel (which implements INotifyPropertyChanged)  then in your View you will be binding it like this:

```
<!--TODO: Content should be placed within the following grid-->
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="ContentRoot">
         <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding BackGroundImage}" CreateOptions="BackgroundCreation" />
        <Button HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="newPic" Click="newPic_Click" >New Kitty</Button>
    </Grid>
```

Whenever you set the BackGroundImage property you will be raising an event called;
`RaisePropertyChanged("BackGroundImage")` -> This is the classical MVVM approach.

So that your view will be aware of the fact that the BackGroundImage is changed and it will load it automatically. (But note that if you just provide a string for this BackGroundImage - you will have to use a converter, a string to Uri converter, since it only accepts Uri's for remote images)

2) "...Is there a way of setting it up so either the old picture remains until the new one is physically ready to be displayed, or alternatively display a placeholder "loading" image until the new one can replace it."

I suggest going with displaying a 'loading' image. I experienced the exact same problem as you do here and my workaround for this was inserting a loading image and setting it's opacity value to 0.1 - along with the actual image. While you are switching between remote URL's, when the previous image disappears the opaque loading image appears and when the next actual image is loaded the loading image is not displayed because new image is overwriting it.

Comment: Thanks for the tips.  MVVM seems a big deal in clr applications, I'll work through the tutorial Johan suggested above when I get a moment

Comment: I don't understand why it is supposed to be a big deal as MVVM pattern perfectly solves a lot of problems for Windows Phone applications.

Comment: You've misunderstood what I was saying, I completely agree, hence why it is a big deal for windows phone applications, coming from Android where MVVM isn't something you see pushed as much.  Having looked at it, I completely accept it's value in windows development, hence why I intend to work through the tutorial on MSDN.  Different platform, different ways of doing things, and that makes sense