# Windows Phone download images - corrupted

Tags: c#, image, windows-phone

When I download image and display it in an ImageView the image is half corrupted.

[image]

```
BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri(
    "http://xxx.xxx.xxx/chatstickerzWinPhone/get_file_from_mysql.php?id=" 
    + getRandomNumber()));
bi.DownloadProgress += handlerDownloadProgress;
Image i = new Image();
i.Tag = iss + "_random_doodle";
//i.DoubleTap += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(clcoRandomDoodle);
i.Hold += new EventHandler<System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs>(clcoRandomDoodle);

i.Width = 440;
i.Height = 300;
//Background = new ImageBrush { ImageSource = bi };
//i.Background = Background;
i.Source = bi;
```

above is my code to download image.

Comment: try the [code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23270448/815938) and see if it makes a difference. The difference is that it specifies `BitmapCreateOptions.IgnoreImageCache`, may refresh the (corrupted) image in the cache? Just a wild guess.

Comment: I tried this , the images are still corrupted

Comment: Does the URL work in a normal browser (i.e. have you confirmed it's not a fault with the code on the server to serve the random image?)

Comment: the images download and show fine when downloaded from a computer browser , its just that when downloaded from windows phone they are corrupt

Comment: its fetching images from an mysql db blob field which is around 100 to 200 KB in size

Comment: any solution for this particular issue?

Answer (score 0):

Use event handler for `BitmapImage`

```
public virtual event EventHandler DownloadCompleted
```

In the handler, use `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()` to set the image source of `Image`.